# How to separate multiple string List taken as input in single line in c#

Tags: c#, string, list

Program takes the input as  list of messages in a single line and here is messages
messages= "email from Ram at 10:10 am" "email from Ramesh at 10:15 am" "email from Rajan at 10:20 am" "email from Rakesh at 10:25 am". These message is taken as input in single line and we have to display it separately in different line
here is my code and I  getting an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
class HelloWorld 
{
  static void Main() 
 {

    string c=Console.ReadLine();
    string[] sl=c.Split("" "");
    foreach(string cc in sl)
        Console.WriteLine(cc);
  }
}
```

Input Format

```
"email from Ram at 10:10 am" "email from Ramesh at 10:15 am" "email from Rajan at 10:20 am" "email from Rakesh at 10:25 am"
```

Expected Output:

```
email from Rakesh at 10:25 am
email from Rajan at 10:20 am
email from Ramesh at 10:15 am
email from Ram at 10:10 am
```

Please help as I am new to c#

Comment: The problem is that your are splitting by whitespace which is included in the  strings you want to preserve.

Comment: not exactly by white space, I waned to split with " " pattern but m getting error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var str = @"email from Ram at 10:10 am"" ""email from Ramesh at 10:15 am"" ""email from Rajan at 10:20 am"" ""email from Rakesh at 10:25 am";

string[] sl=str.Trim().Split(new string[] { "\" \"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach(string st in sl) {
    Console.WriteLine(st);
}
```

**Output:**

> email from Ram at 10:10 am
>
> email from Ramesh at 10:15 am
>
> email from Rajan at 10:20 am
>
> email from Rakesh at 10:25 am

Check results here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zlfJf

Comment: Remeber to trim the leading and trailing - " - character

Comment: getting error as Argument `#1' cannot convert `string' expression to type `char[]'

Comment: Try this `c.Split("\" \"".ToCharArray())`

Comment: even with this c.Split("\" \"".ToCharArray()) not getting expected output

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use additional `"` as they are part of the string literal. And they will be interpreted by the compiler as a single ":

```
var str = @"email from Ram at 10:10 am"" ""email from Ramesh at 10:15 am"" ""email from Rajan at 10:20 am"" ""email from Rakesh at 10:25 am";            
var splitted = str.Split(new string[] { @""" """ }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or another way:

Try to use `Split`:

```
var str = @"email from Ram at 10:10 am"" ""email from Ramesh at 10:15 am"" ""email from Rajan at 10:20 am"" ""email from Rakesh at 10:25 am";
var splitted = str.Split(new []{ '"'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(s=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```